# Need to center widgets

Tags: css

I have tried: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html. I am a newbie and still learning. Nothing works. Even tried  to no avail. It stays to the left!

I am using Cm4all and do the widgets manually in File Manager with Netfirms. They had me:

1. Log into the control panel with your account username and password.
2. Click on ‘FileManager’ under ‘Website’.
3. Click on ‘Settings’.
4. Check the checkbox ‘Use Richtext Editor’.

**Then:**

I also called the number you instructed and they said:

centering big groups of content, or centering groups of one specific object on your site can be done with divs and css.

Here are some hyperlinks to instructions/tutorials for common website operations like this.

They gave me three links but can't post the question with the links, says I need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links.

Nothing I do will make it leave the left side!!

Comment: What exactly is the issue you're having? Can you provide samples of the code that is giving you trouble? If possible can you set up a demo fiddle?

Comment: You need to show us the code you are working with. Create a demo at jsFiddle or CodePen, or post your demo code here.